# Control a COGNEX Barcode Scanner via RS-232

Tags: python-3.x, barcode-scanner, pyserial, cognex

I have a RS-232 Barcode scanner. I'm using a serial port to communicate with the instrument, I don't have a problem communicating with the instrument, the problem I have is that every time I read the scanner response, exist this "extra characters" that I need to remove from my string. I think could be because the way I'm reading the response?

This is what I read from the scanner: "b'0937J094ZP'"
When in theory, the scanner should read only "0937J094ZP"

Do not why the string has an "b" and " ' "

```
cognex = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=5)
time.sleep(.5)
cognex.write(b'0')
time.sleep(1)
response = cognex.read(10)
cognexsn = response
print(cognexsn)
>>>b'0937J094ZP'
```

Thanks for stop by and your help is appreciate.

Comment: `print(cognexsn.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelO, 
I have figure it out, please see as following: 

    cognex.write(b'0')
    time.sleep(1)
    response = cognex.readline()
    cognexsn = response
    print(cognexsn)
    cognexsn = cognexsn.decode()
    print(cognexsn)
    cognexsn = cognexsn.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace(' ','')
    print(cognexsn)

Thank you, for now, I have considered this issue as solved. 

Thank you

Comment: Hi I found the way to do it. please see as following:
    cognex.write(b'0')
    time.sleep(1)
    response = cognex.readline()
    cognexsn = response
    print(cognexsn)
    cognexsn = cognexsn.decode()
    print(cognexsn)
    cognexsn = cognexsn.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace(' ','')
    print(cognexsn)